# How to import vuetify/lib while using vuetify loader in A-La-Carte system

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

While using `A-La-Carte` system in `vuetify` with `vuetify-loader` I got a typescript error while importing `vuetify/lib`, I am unable to understand what I am doing wrong here. Need some help to import this.

I was following this [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/guides/a-la-carte#vuetify-loader)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib' // Error line
import 'vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl'

Vue.use(Vuetify)
```

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'vuetify/lib'. '/Users/.../vuetify/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

I have tried replacing it with below line but it didn't work as well.

```
const Vuetify = require('vuetify/lib');
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Add `vuetify` in `compilerOptions` > `types` of your `tsconfig.json`

It should look like this:

```
{
 compilerOptions: {
    //other options here
    "types": ["vuetify"],
 }
}
```

Save and reload your `vscode`.

Answer (score -2):

we use `vue add vuetify` approach to add Vuetify into our project.

The generated file plugins/vuetify.ts has this line:

**Change this to:**

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';
```

**this**

```
 `import Vuetify from 'vuetify';`
```

remove /lib from the import,
it will solve the issue

Comment: Doesn't this get rid of treeshaking?  https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/#importing-from-lib